# How to clear form in MVC - ajax.actionlink

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I tried to clear the form controller and using  ModelState.Clear(); but don't work. I want to clear the form after the form is saved to database. Is there any possibility to refresh the view and clear the form jquery.

```
 <td>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Show Post Order", "_ListPost", new { idOrder = @item.IdOrder }, new AjaxOptions()
               {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   LoadingElementId = "divLoading",
                   UpdateTargetId = "divPosition",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

               }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </td>
                <td>


                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Answer", "_AddPost", new { idZlecenia = @item.IdZlecenia }, new AjaxOptions()
               {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   LoadingElementId = "divLoadingForm",
                   UpdateTargetId = "divAddPozycje",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

               }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </td>

            </tr>
            ...
            <tr id="divAddPozycje"></tr>
        }

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public PartialViewResult _AddPost(int idOrder, AddPositionViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var findOrder = db.Order.Find(idOrder);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                OrderPosition position = new OrderPosition { Description = viewModel.Description };
                db.OrderPosition.Add(position);
                findOrder.OrderPositionList.Add(position);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Information = position;                  
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            ModelState.Clear();
            return PartialView();              
        }
```

> And View _AddPost - Paritial View. This partialView add position to
>   orders. The item is added using Html Ajax that adds an item without
>   page refresh

```
@model AplikacjaHelpDesk.ViewModels.AddPositionViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Post";
    Layout = null;
}

<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>   
<div class="container-fluid">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "divformResult",
        HttpMethod = "Post"

    }))    
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Hidden("IdOrder")
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 ">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }        
</div>
```

...

Comment: Why can't you `return RedirectToAction("action name", "controller name")`?

Comment: Usual way to clear a form is `document.getElementById('formID').reset();`. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Looks like you are posting the form data using form submit. there are two ways you can do one is redirect to whichever action you want else try to use jquery ajax form submit.

Comment: I wanted to do it without overloading the view

Comment: Where is your form in this question ?

Comment: I want to clean the form partialview _AddPost